# Elevation angle estimation from L-shaped antenna array

Tags: fft, array-signal-processing, point-cloud

I have TI IWR6843ISK-ODS radar sensor and need point cloud data as output from it. The antenna arrangement is as follows:
[image]

I would like to know how to estimate elevation angle with this antenna arrangement. For azimuth angle, I am taking fft along channels 1-4-5-8 and then finding peaks. But if i apply the same to elevation i.e. along channels 8-7-12-11 then its not working and generated point cloud is incorrect. The chirp order here is Tx0, Tx2, Tx1.

Also, as mentioned in the picture, channels in red are 180 degree out of phase wrt blue channels and I am multiplying it with -1 to apply this phase compensation but it doesnt seems to be working.

Can someone help me in understanding how to estimate elevation angles using this antenna arrangement?

Thank you for your time.